# How to get Bash execution time in milliseconds under Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I've checked [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively), but the solution provided did not work for me.

Using date I can get the execution time in seconds:

```
T="$(date +%s)"
#some work here
T="$(($(date +%s)-T))"
echo "execution time (secs) ${T}"
```

However, when I try this:

```
T="$(date +%s%N)"
#some work here
T="$(($(date +%s%N)-T))"
```

Adding %N (as above) to the date to get the nano-second precision I get the following error:
-bash: 1369320760N: value too great for base (error token is "1369320760N")

Does anyone know how to measure the execution time in milliseconds using bash under Mac OS X?

Comment: Do you really need nano second resolution? Which this approach you have a lot of overhead. With `# some work here` ommited, I get times from 0.2 to 0.3 sec -- what should be zero (or at least constant) to reach your goal. Whereas `/usr/bin/time usleep 50000` gives a reasonale stable time of 0.05 +/- 0.01 sec. (Only tested in Linux, don't know if /usr/bin/time and/or usleep is available on OSX.)

Comment: Are you sure the internal clock resolution offers ACCURATE resolution down to the nano-second level?

Answer (score 19):

Since OSX is a BSD-ish system, it's strftime library doesn't have `%N` (http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=date)

Does the bash builtin `time` command give you information you need?

```
time some work here
```

Comment: thanks for making it clear, time works perfectly and outputs three results, but I need to specifically work with the initial and final times.

Answer (score 16):

I would go this route if I needed milliseconds and BSD didn't support date `+%s%N`

```
perl -MTime::HiRes -e 'printf("%.0f\n",Time::HiRes::time()*1000)'
```

Comment: thanks!!! That's THE solution nobody was reporting around...

Comment: and this also works in most unix systems since Perl is available by default in most distributions. But its not as cheap as using `date` or `EPOCHREALTIME`

Comment: and this also works in most unix systems since Perl is available by default in most distributions. But its not as cheap as using `date` or `EPOCHREALTIME`

Answer (score 8):

If you install `coreutils` you can use the GNU Linux `date` by writing `gdate`.

coreutils is available with Homebrew : `brew install coreutils`.

Comment: Also, per [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69332), running `brew info coreutils` provides you with the command to add to your shell's startup script to load the gnu utilities first.

Answer (score 3):

<s>`echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))`</s>

This would convert from nano-seconds to milli-seconds.

From @mpy, `date +%s.%N` works.

Output is different between linux and OS X though:
linux: `1369322592.573787111`
OS X: `1369322610.N`

Comment: I am getting the following error: -bash: 1369321446N: value too great for base (error token is "1369321446N")this does not work in mac osx, I am getting:

Comment: Well, that's annoying... (tested on wrong window) seeing same error :/

Comment: No need to divide the output, just use `date +%s.%N` (but I can't check on OSX; it's working on Linux). But the problem then is, that `bash`'s `$(( ))` IMHO isn't able to handle floating point numbers.

Comment: @mpy That works on osx. Same out for the first 10 chars, acts differently between linux and OS X though.

Comment: Does that mean we cannot get the nano second information using date?

Comment: @LangerHansIslands: Related on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16465702/2037712

Comment: The last letter the `N` is not supported by macOS, but the way `date` function works is that it echos what it does not understand, try `date +%s.%Nthis_is_not_parsed` and you will get `1676542263.Nthis_is_not_parsed`

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer's mentioned, OS X's date doesn't support %N (nanoseconds).

Could you just save the commands to time as a script? Or use a subshell or command group for them:

```
time (sleep 0.1; echo a; sleep 0.1)
time { sleep 0.1; echo a; sleep 0.1; }
```

Or sum the times of individual commands:

```
$ time=$(TIMEFORMAT=%R; (time sleep 0.1; echo a) 2>&1 > /dev/null)
$ time+=+$(TIMEFORMAT=%R; (time sleep 0.1) 2>&1)
$ bc <<< $time
.206
```

Or use some scripting language:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts "%.3f" % Time.now'
1369329611.046
$ time ruby -e '""'
0.029
$ time ruby -e 'puts "%.3f" % Time.now'
1369329622.943
0.029
```

`%.3f` is a format specifier for a floating point number with 3 decimal points. [Time.now](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#now-method) is a class method of the Time class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please describe the ruby code above?

Comment: In `ruby -e 'puts "%.3f" % Time.now'`, `ruby` calls the ruby interpreter, `-e` executes the script that follows on the command line.  `puts` is ruby's `printf` (sort of), `Time` is a ruby object and `Time.now` is the seconds since the epoch.  Using `%.3f` trims the output to 3 decimal places, which is milliseconds (the ".046" and ".943" parts of the output.)

Comment: Also, `time` is a command line tool that times how long it takes to run the command that follows.  See `man time` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Glenn is right, `time` is the command you are looking for, but in order to parse out the info you want, you will need to pass it along to some other processor like `sed`.

`time command-goes-here >/dev/null 2>$1|sed rules-go-here`

This command will get rid of the output from the command itself (sending both standard and error outputs to /dev/null), and pass the time results to sed, where you will need to choose the appropriate rules to edit the stream, and output the desired value.